# How is this usage of 選ばれる understood?

Tags: meaning

I encountered an odd use of 選ばれる in the sentences below:

> 毎年「流行語大賞」が選ばれている

> 本屋大賞はなぜ選ばれるのですか

It is weird to say that "[award] gets selected" in English. How is 選ばれる best understood here?

Comment: If anything is odd in that sentence, it's not 選ばれる but 流行語大賞. It should be understood as referring to the winner of the award, not the award itself.

Comment: @aguijonazo 大賞受賞者 is sometimes abbreviated as 大賞?

Comment: Not specific to 大賞, but also any award/prize, place in ranking (such as 1位) etc. can indicate the person/group/object that receiving it, according to context (and therefore I'm not sure if it can be simply seen as abbreviation)

Answer (score 3):

選ばれる in this context refers to the fact that a winner is selected (as in, somebody designed an award, criteria and goes through the process of finding candidates and selecting the winner).

E.g. 毎年「流行語大賞」が選ばれている simply means they every year do 流行語大賞. This sentence: 本屋大賞はなぜ選ばれるのですか asks why they have 本屋大賞.

You can also say things like 選ばれる旅行会社　仲間は選ばないと　選んでる場合ではない etc.